# How to add a score counter to my tic tac toe

Tags: java, swing, counter, tic-tac-toe

I have a tic tac toe game created with java swing and I want to add a counter to score how many games have been won by either player.
I just need a counter that counts the score and I don't know how to add this

This is my code below:

```
package Game;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static  boolean playerTurn = true;
    public static  boolean playerWon = false;
    public static  boolean computerWon = false;
    public static  boolean playing = true;
    public static  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static  boolean playAgain = false;


    public static  tictactoe board = new tictactoe();

    public static void main(String[] args){
            if(board.isVisible() == false){
                board.setVisible(true);

    if(playerWon == true || computerWon == true){

    System.out.println("Would you like to play again!? true or false");
    playAgain = scan.nextBoolean();
    if(playAgain == true ){
    board.setVisible(false);
    System.out.println("Player1 Won: " + playerWon);
    System.out.println("Player2 Won: " + computerWon);
    board.button1.setText("");
    board.button2.setText("");
    board.button3.setText("");
    board.button4.setText("");
    board.button5.setText("");
    board.button6.setText("");
    board.button7.setText("");
    board.button8.setText("");
    board.button9.setText("");                                              
    playerTurn = true;
    playerWon = false;
    computerWon = false;
    board.setVisible(true);
    else 

    System.out.println("Thanks for playing...! ");}
```

Comment: Create two public variables (for player one and player two) and increase the right one when the game is over. Btw: There is no code from you.

Comment: Hi just edited with the code included

Comment: In your `Main` class you can add like I said before 2 variables and increase them if `checkforwin()` returns true. But please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How do I add two variables and subsequently increase them for each win?

Comment: You haven't posted your `Main` class so I can not really help you.

Comment: How do I implement the counter in the main class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and tell me if it works. I added a comment, where I have changed code.

```
public static  boolean playerTurn = true;
        public static  boolean playerWon = false;
        public static  boolean computerWon = false;
        public static  boolean playing = true;
        public static  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        public static  boolean playAgain = false;
        public static  int     player1WinCount = 0; //At game start nobody has won
        public static  int     player2WinCount = 0;


        public static  tictactoe board = new tictactoe();

        public static void main(String[] args){
                if(board.isVisible() == false){
                    board.setVisible(true);

    // Here I added the information about the counter    

        if (playerWon == true) {
            player1WinCount++;
            System.out.println("The player has won " + player1WinCount + " time(s)");
        }

        if (computerWon == true) {
            player2WinCount++;
            System.out.println("The computer has won " + player2WinCount + " time(s)");
        }

        if(playerWon == true || computerWon == true){

        System.out.println("Would you like to play again!? true or false");
        playAgain = scan.nextBoolean();
        if(playAgain == true ){
        board.setVisible(false);
        System.out.println("Player1 Won: " + playerWon);
        System.out.println("Player2 Won: " + computerWon);
        board.button1.setText("");
        board.button2.setText("");
        board.button3.setText("");
        board.button4.setText("");
        board.button5.setText("");
        board.button6.setText("");
        board.button7.setText("");
        board.button8.setText("");
        board.button9.setText("");                                              
        playerTurn = true;
        playerWon = false;
        computerWon = false;
        board.setVisible(true);
        else 

        System.out.println("Thanks for playing...! ");}
```